# An if statement to a variable SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When I run a procedure (below), the "Execute procedure" popup box requests a value which is what I expect. If I complete the value or I pass a null value it runs as expected.

What I am after is if I don't select pass null value or leave the value field blank the query will run for all fields, effectively ignoring the line:

```
Where userid = @userID
```

Hope this makes sense and is this possible?

This is the query I execute (I didn't create this):

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON  
GO  
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON  
GO  

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Codename]   
    @userID NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS  
    EXECUTE dbo.ProcedureToRun @userID  
    RETURN 0
```

The query it executes (there are several of these types of queries in the procedure)

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Screen), COUNT(*) AS Visits  
FROM HitCounters  
WHERE userid = @userID  
  AND HitDate > DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())  
GROUP BY Screen
```

Thanks,

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function on a column, it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and works on the whole selected rows. Remove those redundant parentheses to make the code clearer! Anyway, no need to select distinct at all here, since the GROUP BY returns no duplicates...

Answer (score 0):

Add this condition to where clause `@userID is null`

```
Select Screen, count(*) AS Visits  
 From HitCounters  
 Where (userid = @userID or @userID is null) AND HitDate  > DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())  
 Group By Screen
```

Comment: That worked and was really simple. I spent an hour getting confused and you and Denis had a result in 30 seconds. I'm going to make the update across about 40 stored procedures unless there is a way to make this work upfront.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Also, as @jarlh described, remove distinct, it is redundant. Group by already apply its purpose. And be careful about usage. It is not a function.

Comment: Also note that this can have query plan/performance implications. If may be  better use and `if ... else` construct with two separate queries.

Answer (score 0):

How to select all records if `@userID` is null

```
Select distinct(Screen), count(*) AS Visits  
From HitCounters  
Where (
    userid = @userID  OR
        @userID IS NULL
    )
    AND HitDate  > DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())  
Group By Screen
```

Comment: Distinct and group by? A bit overkill.